# add the count of child node in each branch of asp.net treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add the count of child node in each branch of asp.net treeview.

for example ..

root (2)

```
 parent (3)
   child
   child
   child
parent (2)
   child
   child
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use code-behind. You could do:

```
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Iterate through the root nodes in the Nodes property.
    for(int i=0; i<YourTreeView.Nodes.Count; i++)
    {
        // Set the text to include children count.
        SetChildNodeText(YourTreeView.Nodes[i]);
    }
}

void SetChildNodeText(TreeNode node)
{
    if(node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
    {
        node.Text += ' (' + node.ChildNodes.Count.ToString() + ')'; // append child node count to the text
    }

    for(int i=0; i<node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        // recursion
        SetChildNodeText(node.ChildNodes[i]);
    }
}
```